# How to return member values in a array of objects using lambda expressions

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin, higher-order-functions

I have an array of "Dog" where i want to print the name of all dogs older then 5 years.

I tried something like

```
Dogs.filter{ it.age > 5 }.forEach { it.name }
```

This gives me the value i need, but how do I store and return it as a list of strings?
I tried things like adding .join(",") but since I don't get any array in return it wont work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) operator:

```
val dogNames: List<String> = dogs.filter { it.age > 5 }.map { it.name }
```

Comment: Yes.. this might be it.
So filter gives me an array of dogs, and map modify the dogs value to a string?
Does that mean map can actually change the List type?

If I have a list, mDogs: List<Dog> and run mDogs.map { it.toCat() } will mDogs nog be mDogs: List<Cat> ?

Comment: The `map` operator returns a `List<R>`, this `R` is whatever type you've returned in its lambda. Since in this case `it.name` is a `String`, it's returning a `List<String>`. This is a brand new list instance, it doesn't modify the original.